# Is it possible to utilize multiple custom authenticators within one application?

Tags: android

I am attempting to leverage an existing application for centralized authentication for multiple consuming applications, instead of standing up a new application ([as listed here](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth)). Is it possible to use the same custom authentication application, but use multiple authenticators within it to store two different types of accounts? So far, I have been unable to get this to work. The current implementation involves saving an account with the name of `com.myaccount` and I would like to save another one through a different login button as `com.myaccount.anothername` but not have to spin up another custom authentication application.

When I call `addAccountExplicitly()` it returns false, but I cannot figure out how to debug this any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I have confirmed that it is indeed possible to use the same application with multiple authenticators. The error was in my own implementation of AbstractAccountAuthenticator.